# How to display empty graph in Grafana even if there is no data

Tags: grafana, dashboard

I'm using Grafana v9.1.8.
I created a panel bases on data from influxdb.

The data only sent when application is working, so sometimes there is no data.
And the dashboard will show just 'No Data' in the middile of the panel without any graph.

[image]

I'm trying to keep the graph(axis) shown even if there's no data, but I cannot find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such feature on Grafana at the moment, but I found this solution:
https://community.grafana.com/t/what-to-show-when-the-panel-is-without-data/66524/9

Make a fake union, check if you have any data and if you don't create some random time data without other parameters. As they say in the answer, this may not be scalable, as you need to add extra lines for each query, but it may be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also figured out something similar. I created a fixed data by using array from influxdb flux. That would keep my graph shown.